# g++: error：unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++2a’

Tags: gcc

I was installing a software in linux, it required "make" to compile, but it showed the error below.

> ```
> g++ -MMD -std=c++2a -I. -Wall  -fopenmp -mpopcnt -O3 -o IBIS.o -c IBIS.cc
> g++: error：unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++2a’
> make: *** [IBIS.o] error1
> ```

It seems the gcc version is too low, and then I update gcc by conda, including gcc8,gcc9,gcc10 and gcc12. the error still exist. what should I do to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For versions 9 and above try `-std=c++20` (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: It shows the same error: g++ -MMD -std=c++2a -I. -Wall  -fopenmp -mpopcnt -O3 -o IBIS.o -c IBIS.cc
g++: error：unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++20’
make: *** [IBIS.o] error1

Comment: I used gcc version 9.5.0 in a conda environment.